# AJAX with Rails 3.0

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I read in [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/ajax_on_rails.html) about AJAX with Rails that "Rails 3.1 ships with jQuery as the default JavaScript library". If I'm using Rails 3.0, how would the use of AJAX differ from what's specified in this guide? (It's hard for me to upgrade Rails version right now.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, same as in Rails 3.1, you add:

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

in your `Gemfile`, if it's not already there (in which case you actually already have it) and run:

```
bundle install
```

And, you will need to run:

```
rails g jquery:install
```

after that.

Comment: OK, and then I should be able to follow everything in the guide, is that right?

Comment: Rails 3.0 does not have asset pipeline, all else should be the same. Guide for 3.0 is here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.0.0/ajax_on_rails.html